# Storing all value of column of database in array using mysqli_num(why not working)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Why cant the output three values store in the array with indexes as number ?
its giving error as follows:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\working_files\admin_home.php on line 63
>   Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\working_files\admin_home.php on line 64

```
    $m_name_detail1_query="SELECT m_name FROM movies";

    $run_m_name_detail1_query=mysqli_query($connection,$m_name_detail1_query);

    $fetch_m_name_details=mysqli_fetch_array($run_m_name_detail1_query,MYSQLI_NUM);


?>          <?php echo $fetch_m_name_details[0] ?>//working
            <?php echo $fetch_m_name_details[1] ?>//not working
            <?php echo $fetch_m_name_details[2] ?>//not working
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysqli_fetch_array()` returns (in your case) a numerically indexed array of a row of data from your SQL statement, as your SQL is

```
$m_name_detail1_query="SELECT m_name FROM movies";
```

each row will only contain 1 value - which is the `$fetch_m_name_details[0]` you find works.

If you want the value from a sequence of rows, use `mysqli_fetch_all()`

```
$fetch_m_name_details=mysqli_fetch_all($run_m_name_detail1_query,MYSQLI_NUM);
```

you will then find `$fetch_m_name_details` will contain an array of rows, so you can use

```
echo $fetch_m_name_details[0][0];
echo $fetch_m_name_details[1][0];
echo $fetch_m_name_details[2][0];
```

if there are at least 3 rows

Comment: There's probably a better canonical for this question that doesn't recommend mannually accessing each element in the 2d array.

Comment: @mickmackusa, don't think I recommended anything. Just provided an example which is relevant to how op was using the data.